# Can we search multiple strings in multiple columns in data tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, datatables

I want to search multiple strings in multiple columns (not all the columns)

```
var val='profile|officer|work'; 
oTable.api().columns([0,1]).search(val, true, false ).draw();
```

I tried above code but its not working

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression seems to be wrong.

If you want to match one of those words you should use this regex expression:

`\bprofile\b|\bofficer\b|\bworker\b`